# ListNode head.next.next = new ListNode(0); what is this error?

Tags: java, syntax

I just want to build a linked list, I do not know the reason of this problem. Could someone help me? Perhaps this is easy, but I cannot figure it out.

[image]

how to solve this problem?

Comment: FIrst of all, you can't use "." in your name variables because is a java reserved word to invoke a method for a class.
Second: what ListNode is?
Third: I think you're pretty much confuse how a LinkedList work

Comment: When you're posting code, use text not images. You wouldn't post a *description* of the Mona Lisa either, would you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> ListNode head = new ListNode(0)
>
> head.next = new ListNode(1)
>
> head.next.next = new ListNode(2)

Do not put ListNode in front of head.next its already defined.